# how to scheadule nest thermostat Heat or Cool Temperature

Tags: ios, iphone, nest, nest-api, firebase-authentication

i Have integrated nest thermostat in my app, Here i can successfully read and write the temperature and other changes.

Here i need to make a schedule Temperature changes like set 70 degree temperature after 3 hours or on Sunday heat to 65 degrees.

I have seen these scheduling implemented in Nest Official application(https://nest.com/support/article/How-do-I-program-a-heating-and-cooling-schedule) , Is it possible for other developers to implement the same functionality with fire-base API , Help me in this if possible please share some references. thanks in advance.

Comment: If any one have idea please answer it

Comment: as per my research i come to know its not possible by Api but i solved my requirement by scheduling local notifications for the particular time with that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the schedule via the API is not available.

Comment: you could custom make your own schedule and change the set points, but it can get tricky.

Comment: Hi urman... can you help how can i set custom  schedule through code ... any reference  for this ...